# How to prevent npm install <package> --save-dev from reordering devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

**Background**
We're having issues with a Windows build system hitting the file path too long error when the node modules folder has items within it that have paths which are over 260 characters.

We've discovered adding a deeply nested dependency to the top of the devDependencies section fixes this issue. The assumption is that when npm sees a nested `dependency C.1` require `package A`, which is already declared and available in devDependencies, npm will not add `dependency A` to `dependency C.1`'s node_modules directory.

**Issue**
The problem I'm seeing on my local machine is that running `npm install <package> --save-dev` reorders the packages in devDependencies alphabetically, but the order npm process packages and their dependencies matters. If I check this in, then the build system will hit the same file path too long error.

ie If `package A` comes after `package C` and `dependency C.1` requires `package A`, then npm will add `package A` to the node_modules folder of `dependency C.1`.

I'm not sure if this reordering is only on my machine since I haven't seen npm reorder dependencies on my home machine before.

Has anyone seen this before or know how to stop this behavior?

**Versions**
Node: v0.10.32
NPM: v1.4.28

Side note: I've read that npm 2.0 or future versions will analyze the dependency hierarchy, find duplicated packages, and only reference them once on the file system, but the upgrade to npm 2.0 is not in the picture at this time.

Comment: `npm shrinkwrap` has the same flaw.

Comment: @Funkodebat Did you notice if this was a recent change? I remember seeing npm just append to the bottom of the list previously.

Comment: actually it might not exist in npm nemore, i had an old version for a while.  I ended up creating a script that only calls `npm shrinkwrap` if it detects `package.json` changed, otherwise it was continually committing shrinkwrap because it kept regenerating

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see this working is to have some sort of preinstall script which [hopefully] will run *after*  the dependencies file has been updated but *before* the package is installed.  [From the npm site](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html):

> In the current version of node, the standard way to do this is using a
>   .gyp file. If you have a file with a .gyp extension in the root of
>   your package, then npm will run the appropriate node-gyp commands
>   automatically at install time

If that doesn't work, you will need to use MakeFile and rewrite the package.json file.  This is not too out of the ordinary as some projects require some sort of pre-compilation - you would just instruct your team to run a separate command for installing npm packages.